# What are the most important differences to note between ref and reactive in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I learned vuejs recently and I seem to be having problems in fully grasping the essential differences between the usage of ref and reactive. When is it right to use ref or reactive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this article](https://antfu.me/posts/composable-vue-vueday-2021?ck_subscriber_id=1481685174&utm_source=convertkit&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=%F0%9F%94%A5+%28%2353%29+Splitting+Slots%20-%207831160#ref-vs-reactive) from **Anthony Fu** (a Vue.js champion) we can summarize it in these points:

- refs are considered as primitives values
- reactives as objects
- refs only mutated by `.value` property, but reactive with any nested property
- reactives looks like plain objects
- reactive objects have some caveats like loosing reactivity when they are destructed.
- reactive objects should be wrapped with function when they're watched like `watch(()=>reactiveObj,(newVal,oldVal)....`, unlike refs which are unwrapped `watch(refProp,(newVal,oldVal)....`

**Conclusion :**

> I’d say go with `ref` whenever you can